# Can i integrate Tkinter with my eclipse for python GUI

Tags: eclipse, tkinter

I was trying to add "Tkinter" in my eclipse . 
Is there anyway I can integrate it with eclipse .

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "add "Tkinter" in my eclipse"

Comment: plugins or something . Like pydev Do we have option to integrate Tkinter also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install PyDev plugin on Eclipse.

Then, you `import tkinter` directly from your python file (as usual)

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.mainloop()
```